# Animating a navigation menu coming in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I have some kind of sticky menu optimised with jQuery. I wrote some code to detect the height we're in and after a certain value bring the navigation down and make it sticky by setting its position value fixed!

Here is the code :

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
            var $locationY = $(window).scrollTop(),
           $defaultY = 385;

           if ( $locationY < $defaultY ){
                $('#nav').removeClass("sticky")
                                        }
                    else {
                        $('#nav').addClass("sticky")
}
     });
```

And the question is how can I animate this? To show up nicely for example slides from top to bottom. I wanna know what's the right approach for using slideDown, animate, ... methods for this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Add a transition with CSS to your sticky class.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is have it position fixed, its top value equal to 0 minus its height. Then animate it to top value 0.

This way it will slide from the top exactly like the facebook timeline menu... The sticky class should have the negative top value, the JS will correct it in animation.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        var $locationY = $(window).scrollTop(),
       $defaultY = 385;

       if ( $locationY < $defaultY ){
            $('#nav').removeClass("sticky")
                                    }
                else {
                    $('#nav').addClass("sticky").animate({top:0},400);
      }
});
```

Comment: Seems like a good approach. But do you know what the animate with the given parameters does? I don't see any duration designation!

Comment: I am sorry I answered a bit too fast. I have corrected the animate call. It receives an object for the CSS properties to animate and the second parameter is the length, 400 being the default you do not need to explicitly send it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/UZgXB/1/

Not sure your sticky menu is shown on load or not.

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('#nav').stop()
                .addClass('sticky')
                .animate({
                'padding': '1% 2% 1% 2%'
            }, 400, "swing");
        } else {
            $('#nav').stop()
                .removeClass('sticky').addClass('normal')
                .animate({
                'padding': '6% 2% 6% 2%'
            }, 400, "swing");
        }
    });
});
```

## CSS

```
#nav, .normal {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:6% 2%;
    width:96%;
    background:red;
}
.sticky {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `transition` can help you.

```
#nav{
     transition:top 2s ease;
}
```

And position the `#nav` using `postion:fixed;` and `top:xxxpx;` like

```
.sticky{
     position:fixed;
     top:300px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CHWsC/) Try it.

Comment: This solution would be a good fit if I wanted the navigation bar be placed *any other* place but top of the browser!

Comment: @AliTabibzadeh Actually you can do it in any direction, the only matter is calculating the position of endpoint, after that,just set `top` or `left` css property via javascript, and transition runs.